# It always falls in 'else' condition. (TimePicker)

Tags: java, android

Good morning guys

1) I'm trying to do compare two time pickers and it's not working so well.
It always gives the same option of - else

```
int firstHouer =fromTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
int firstdMinute =fromTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
int seccoundHouer = fromTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
int seccoundMinute =fromTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();

       if (firstHouer + firstdMinute < seccoundHouer + seccoundMinute) 
       {
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "B" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              toast.show();
       }
       else
       {
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              toast.show();
       }
```

2) And I have another problem when I put the ": " symbol, the text changes it's direction

[pic of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnzbL.jpg)

Comment: Can you try add Thread.sleep() between first and second hours variable

Comment: It is always a good practice to wrap nested conditions in brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare relative 24 hour times, you should convert both the hour and minute components to the *same* unit, and then compare.  For example, to compare both using minutes:

```
int firstHouer = fromTimePicker.getHour();     // getCurrentHour() is deprecated
int firstdMinute = fromTimePicker.getMinute(); // getCurrentMinute() is deprecated
int seccoundHouer = toTimePicker.getHour();    // or whatever it is called
int seccoundMinute = toTimePicker.getMinute(); // or whatever it is called

if (60*firstHouer + firstdMinute < 60*seccoundHouer + seccoundMinute) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "B" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
else {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

Edit: As @Dennis just pointed out, you also have a typo in your code, and you're using the same `TimePicker` for both sets of times, which probably is not what you want.

Comment: Also, he/she is using the same `TimePicker` object.

Comment: getCurrentHour() & getCurrentMinute() is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker). It is suggested to use getHour() & getMinute().

Comment: @SuryakantBharti What I have done in the past was to bind an `OnTimeSetListener` callback, which gets passed the hour and minute as parameters.  Then, we don't even need to directly call anything on the time picker.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yours is a "Great Idea"! But, I was just suggesting for the OP. :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for removing deprecated methods. :)

Comment: @SuryakantBharti Good catch, but in any case that wasn't the main point of the OP's question, and at least the code still would have _run_ with those methods being used, despite it not being optimal.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, you are right. But, I have repulsion towards deprecated technology. In Android, GCM, Framework Fragments, Framework Loaders, etc have been deprecated. Still, people keep using/mentioning these. This is not correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are determining the hours and minutes twice right after each other.
The execution is so fast (evenon slow machines) that the values will hardly ever be different, only right on the switch of a minute (or hour, but in that case the else will also be triggered, because of the problem described by Tim in his answer).

If you try your code very often, you will sooner or later hit exactly the point where the first getting of minutes is different and lower than the second getting, in the same hour. Then you will hit the `then` part.